# How do I quit being a russian Tsarina and turn swedish?

Tags: mount-and-blade, mount-and-blade-with-fire-and-sword

So I joined the Muscovite Tsardom, overthrew that rubbish Dmitry guy through the main quests, and became Tsarina! Huzzah! I've been leading our armies to victory over those incessantly war-hungry Swedes.

Unfortunately, I have more than a few vassals who are too.. quarrelsome. Anything I seem to do, they get upset, and despite my brilliant leadership, I'm now banned from half the russian fortresses in the land!

I'm starting to tire of being Russia's tsarina, with all the annoyed lords and the vomit-green colour we adopted for our signs. Though my bloodline claims to russian royalty are obviously legitimate and unquestionable, I'm thinking of being the rightful heir to the Swedish throne, or maybe starting my own, rebellious queendom.

Unfortunately, I can't find any way to abdicate the position as head of state for Russia! I can't seem to offer my vassalship to Swede King Carl Gustaf, who I have great relations with; I can't fight for a claimant because they think I'm too loyal to myself; And nobody I talk to in Russia wants to discuss my abdication, despite all the hate.

Jacques Cleménte always says he's too busy to talk, too, I thought we could reminisce about the old times, but even he's beginning to dislike me, clearly.

Is there any way to free myself from these political shackles, or am I cemented in the peoples' minds as a russo-primadonna? I'm willing to consider reality-bending cheats, if they're the only option.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I don't think that such a way even exists. In the world of Mount&Blade (any game of the series) there is no way to stop being a faction leader with the only exception of being overthrown/your entire faction dismissed and leave the land.

Yes, diplomacy of M&B is strange. Sometimes it's very strange. But all you can do is to install some mod and hope for the best or deal with existing problems.